# send mail with SNDDST

Tags: ibm-midrange, control-language

I'm trying to send out an email from my as400 unsuccessfully!
I'm using this code into a CLLE:

```
SNDDST     TYPE(*LMSG) TOINTNET((*NONE) +
       ('address1@mail.it') +           
       ('address2@mail.it')) DSTD('TEST') +
LONGMSG('test mail...')
```

I received an error for my user that I fixed with WRKDIRE where I added the user, in fact now when I call the program, read into dspjoblog: The sending of the distribution was completed successfully.
But I do not receive anything in mailboxes

I think that SMTP configuration is OK but I receive this error:

```
      Tipo    Tipo   ----Registrata----               -----Mittente-----  Num. 
Opz Funzione  voce   Data       Ora      Nome lav.    ID utente  Indir.   seq  
     *RTR    *ERR   10/04/12  13:04:15  QMSF         MARCO     MT        0013 


Funzione . . . . . . . . . . :   Instradamento distribuzione  
Lavoro . . . . . . . . . . . :   275842/QMSF/QMSF             
Data/ora . . . . . . . . . . :   10/04/12  13:04:15           

Mittente:                                                     
ID utente/Indirizzo  . . . :   MARCO     MT                 
Nome sistema/Gruppo. . . . :   S6518B7A                     
Numero di sequenza . . . . . :   0013                         
Data/ora di origine  . . . . :   10/04/12  13:04:15           
Agente destinazione  . . . . :   OfficeVision                 

Codice stato SNADS . . . . . :   0001 Errore instradamento    
Destinatario in errore:                                       
ID utente/Indirizzo  . . . :   INTERNET  GATEWAY            
Nome sistema/Gruppo  . . . :   INTERNET                     
Voce indirizzario sistema  :   Definito localmente
```

I've found this error:

```
Message. . . : Failed opening file IFS (Integrated File System)
on file/MMAIL/temp/Q6.txt
Cause. . . . . : The RTCP function requires the use of a file IFS (Integrated
   File System) / MMAIL/temp/Q6.txt. The error received by the call is 3025.
   This file does not exist in the system is blocked or damaged and can not
    be used at the time.
Correction. . . : Close MSF (Mail System Framework) "ENDMSF" and restart
 "STRMSF".
```

I've just tried to restart job without success and always in QMSF job this error log:

```
Message ID. . . . . : Severity CPFAF98. . . . . . . : 60
Message type. . . . : Informational
Submit Date. . . . . . : 13/04/12 Time sent. . . . . . : 12:44:02

Message. . . : The job has stopped processing 320083/QMSF/QMSF
  MSF message.
Cause. . . . . : The program exit point in the library QTMSFWD QTCP
  to the point of exit QIBM_QZMFMSF_MSG_FWD has detected a condition with
  6518B7A0909081414210000000008 the message ID. The message indicates that
  processing must be completed. The MSF message will be revised
  the next command execution STRMSF (Start Mail Server Framework)
Correction. . . : Determine because the program exit point has
  indicated the need to end processing of a message. in
  joblog may be listed messages that have caused
  incorrect program. Correct errors, and run the
ENDMSF command (closing mail server framework) to terminate
```

Comment: Do you have the SMTP server setup properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start by looking at SNADS logs using DSPDSTLOG.

IBM support document "SNADS - Basic Troubleshooting Process" is very helpful in finding the source of error. Hope this helps...

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=nas1b56c1c34b489e7528625663d004b1797

Comment: could you check whether file "/MMAIL/temp/Q6.txt" is exist. If exist, give authority to *public then restart the mail server  ("ENDMSF" then "STRMSF").

Comment: /MMAIL/temp is empty. but when this file is created?

Comment: It is better if you refer to [http://www.easy400.net/mmailh/faq.htm](http://www.easy400.net/mmailh/faq.htm)  From that web page,Click at "2. The e-mail messages do not arrive to their destinations". You can read short explanation about "/MMAIL/temp". I have setup mail in our as/400 many years ago - i have forgot most of the details. As far as i can remember, initially the mail not working properly due to some wrong settings somewhere.

Comment: Don't know if this helps - check last forum post from [http://www.mcpressonline.com/forum/showthread.php?15131-email-problem-%28QMSF-CPFAF98%29](http://www.mcpressonline.com/forum/showthread.php?15131-email-problem-%28QMSF-CPFAF98%29) . If still does not work, it is better to ask at this forum [http://www.systeminetwork.com/forums](http://www.systeminetwork.com/forums) . Many as/400 experts use System iNetwork Forums instead of stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

There are many things to check.  Since you haven't described the things you *did* do, it is difficult to suggest other things you *could* do.  May I suggest some reading material?

- http://www.easy400.net/mmail/start
- http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/iseries/v5r2/ic2928/info/rzair/rzair.pdf
- http://mowyourlawn.com/RPGMail.html

Answer (score 1):

Try using @Buck Calabro's links and here are a couple others. SMTP may not be fully setup right.

- http://www.bvstools.com/docs/mailtool/faq.html
- http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=%2Frzair%2Frzairsmtppa.htm